# How can I create a fully debuggable self-contained nuget package (lib, pdb, and source) for a C++ library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, nuget

I have a C++ library that I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2022 and must publish to an internal nuget feed (plain network share folder).  Is there a way to include the pdb files and source code for the library with the package in such a way that it is fully debuggable (in Visual Studio 2022) on machines that do not have access to the source control repo?  Currently, I'm using a .nuspec file to build the package.  I'm aware of SourceLink, but have been unable to find any mention of using it with a plain folder in the package instead of a hosted cloud service.  I don't have a lot of options for spinning up services or using external resources, and I don't really care if the debugging material bloats the package since it's only for consumption by a small internal development group.

Here's what my current .nuspec file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Corp.MyLib.Cpp</id>
    <version>0.1.0.0</version>
    <description>My library</description>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <tags>native, nativepackage, mylib, C++, Corp</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="native0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  
  <files>
    <!-- Targets & Props -->
    <file src=".\Corp.MyLib.Cpp.targets" target="build\native\Corp.MyLib.Cpp.targets" />
    <!-- All header files -->
    <file src="..\Build\**\*.h" target="lib\native\include" />
    <!-- Binaries -->
    <!-- 
      Project is already configured to build outputs to appropriate subpath under lib
      \win\$(PlatformTarget)\win-$(PlatformTarget)-$(Configuration)\$(PlatformToolset)
      Ex: \win\x86\win-x86-Release\v143\mylib.lib
    -->
    <file src="..\Build\Lib\**" target="build\native\lib\" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a subfolder named lib aside  your.nuspec . Put .dll,  lib, exp. pdb file   in lib folder.

2.Add  `<file src="lib\**" target="lib" />`

3.After nuget packg, you could check  the package by modifying the file name extension to zip , and there will be a lib  folder.

Note: unlike C#, you need to manually add the library as dependency after downloading the native package.

your.nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <authors>AuthorName</authors>
    <owners>OwnerName</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description here</description>
    <releaseNotes>Release notes here</releaseNotes>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    
    <file src="*" target="content" />
<file src="lib\**" target="lib" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Where does the source code go, and how can I make sure when it's debugged on another machine that the debugger can locate it?

Comment: In the sample, I put the source files next to the .nuspec file with the target name content and the source files will be automatically added to the project.

Comment: Make sure the DLL can be found at runtime: You can copy the DLL file to the same directory as the executable, or add the DLL  path to your system's PATH environment variable